# two loops in a function?

Tags: java, loops

Is it possible to have two loops in a function?

```
public static void reduce(Rational fraction){
    int divisorNum = 0;
    int n = 2;
    while(n < fraction.num){
        if(fraction.num % n == 0){
            divisorNum = n;
            System.out.println("n: " + divisorNum);
            n++;
        }   
    }

    int divisorDenom = 1;
    int m = 2;
    while(m<fraction.denom){
        if(fraction.denom % m == 0){
            divisorDenom = m;
            System.out.println("m: " + divisorDenom);
            m++;
        }   
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the greatest common denominator. I know this is the very long way about doing this problem but I just wanted to try having two loops. When I call this function, only the first loop gets printed and not the second. I originally had an if statement, but seeing that the second loop doesn't execute I figured that I fix this part first.

Here's my other part of the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Rational fraction = new Rational();
        fraction.num = 36;
        fraction.denom = 20; 
        reduce(fraction);
    }
```

Comment: **Yes**, it is. Why it wouldn't be possible?

Comment: Please consider how easy it is to answer this question yourself. You will train yourself to be incapable of self-discovery which is an invaluable attribute.

Comment: @Kadne, for some weird reason mine doesn't print the if part. Thus I thought once it finished a loop it automatically exited out of the function.

Comment: Understand the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: @jasonadams - Please post all the relevant details of your problem in the question part itself, not in this comment section.

Comment: The only limit is you cannot have more then 64K byte code bytes in your method.  This is approximately a few thousand lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. There are no limitations
Watch your conditional test = is not quite ==

Based on your edit  I suspect fraction.denom is initialized at 1 or 0
Hence you will never get in the second loop

Comment: Now you get down voted for helping? Guys, are you forgetting what SO is about? If you are in desperate need for bashing please go back to your video games.

Comment: Agree,same with my answer.

Comment: Good catch with the = and ==.

Comment: Hey MonoThreaded, my fraction.numerator is 36 and my fraction.denominator is initialized to 20. but my constructor: this.numerator = 0, this.denominator = 1. I'm not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: if fraction.denom == 1, you will never get in the loop  since 2 < 1 is not likely.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. You even can have 3 if you try hard enough.

EDIT: The didactic version:

Loops, as the name suggest, are constructs that allow you to repeat blocks of code several times (post conditional loops -> until certain condition is met keep running, pre conditional loops -> if certain condition is met, keep running). This is often called "iteration". So in a typical for-loop:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
    print(array[i]);
```

You can say you're "iterating" over the array 10 times.

This has nothing to do with functions. You can have several loops inside a function, or functions being called inside loops. As long as you define your "blocks" of code (with begining and ending braces) you do what you think its best.

Comment: why should OP *try hard*?

Comment: @AmitJoki I'd start with *trying at all* :|

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are no limitations when it comes to looping. You could do 1000 while loops if you wanted.

An example here could be doing something like making a square out of `*`...
Here's an example

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{  
   for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
   { 
       System.out.print("*"); 
   } 
   System.out.println(); 
}
```

It would look like:

```
  ****
  ****
  ****
  ****
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have any number of loops in your function :-

1.You can have nested loops;
2.Two loops side by side.

SO,your piece of code is fine enough considering the value of n, until the conditions for loop execution are met :-

```
public static void ....
while(n<x){
    do this
    add to counter
}

while(m<x){
    do this
    add to counter
}

if(y==z){                // NOTE :- Here you have committed mistake, compare using ==, not by =(it will be always true else and your condition will always be met else)
    print this
}
```

Comment: @jasonadams - You need to have a thorough look at this code, I have made some edit. You need to compare using ==.